# PayPal shows empty cart

Tags: php, paypal

I have two payment pages for different things.  One of them works great and posts the cart to PayPal like it should, the other one shows an empty cart regardless.  I've looked through the url string I'm sending to and these are the only arguments that are different:

Works:

```
&item_name_1=Add+Seats+-+Keynote+Manager
&item_number_1=Add+to+License
&amount_1=68
&quantity_1=1
&notify_url=http%3A%2F%2Frevolutiondesign.biz%2FIPNBroker.php%3Fkey%3DAZHJ0T1U05V1W1XY8G1C3C3XP3IMF2N2PP%26extendYears%3D0%26newSeats%3D1%26addPortable%3D%26newFeatures%3D
&custom=upgrade
&key=AZHJ0T1U05V1W1XY8G1C3C3XP3IMF2N2PP
&extendYears=0
&newSeats=1
&addPortable=
&addFeatures=
&qtyAddFeatures=0
&costAddFeatures=0
&qtyAddSeats=1
&costAddSeats=68
&qtyPortable=
&costPortable=
&qtyExtend=0
&costExtend=0
&v=63400
```

Doesn't:

```
&item_name_1=Add+Cloud+Seats
&item_number_1=Add+Cloud+Seats
&amount_1=94
&quantity_1=1
&notify_url=http%3A%2F%2Frevolutiondesign.biz%2FIPNBroker.php%3FcustomerID%3Dba3d3c75-5e18-42b7-948e-3e34cccc1d9e%26extendPeriod%3Dmonths%26qtyExtend%3D1%26qtyAddSeats%3D1
&custom=cloudUpgrade
&cstID=ba3d3c75-5e18-42b7-948e-3e34cccc1d9e
&costAddSeats=97
&costExtend=7
&v=GREAT+Design+Group
&extend=1
&extendPeriod=months
&add=1
```

Is there any difference that anyone can see that would cause the second one not to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok through some process of elimination I finally identified the issue.  The issue was in the presence of the variable called 'Add'.  I was using that for the number of licenses the user wanted to add, but PayPal [also has that as a variable for cart transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) which I did not realize.  I pulled that post data into a php variable and then unset the post so it didn't pass to PayPal and it works now.  I could also have renamed that post variable coming from my purchase page and I bet it would work as well.